# Convert arrays to properties of a new class using the map operator

Tags: arrays, dart

I've two arrays/Lists:

*users =[object1,object2,object3];* all of the same type: *Class User*

*teams =[object1,object2,object3];* all of the same type: *Class Team*

I want to create a new array dynamically containing objects of type *SupportTeams* which has properties of type User and Team.

I think I should use the map operator to convert the arrays to my new array.

Something like this

```
List<SupportTeams> combiner(List<User> users, List<Team> teams) {
    return users.map((user) {
      teams.map((team) {
        SupportTeams(user,team);
      });
    }).toList();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. First thing's first, you need to return from your calls within `map`:

```dart
List<SupportTeams> combiner(List<User> users, List<Team> teams) {
    return users.map((user) {
      return teams.map((team) {
        return SupportTeams(user,team);
      });
    }).toList();
  }
```

However, this still won't work 100% as you'll have a list of lists. You'll need to flatten the result using `expand`:

```dart
List<SupportTeams> combiner(List<User> users, List<Team> teams) {
    return users.map((user) {
      return teams.map((team) {
        return SupportTeams(user,team);
      });
    }).expand((i) => i).toList();
  }
```

If you want to be even more concise, you can use `=>` notation instead of returns:

```dart
List<SupportTeams> combiner(List<User> users, List<Team> teams) =>
    users.map((user) =>
      teams.map((team) => 
        SupportTeams(user,team))).expand((i) => i).toList();
```

Finally, as @lrn pointed out in the comments you can use control flow collections to do this much more cleanly:

```dart
List<SupportTeams> combiner(List<User> users, List<Team> teams) => [
  for (var user in users)
    for (var team in teams)
      SupportTeams(user, team)
];
```

Comment: You can also do: `var result = [for (var user in users) for (var team in teams) SupportTeams(user, team)];`.

Comment: Ah of course! I totally forgot about that... :-) I'll edit the answer to include that.